# MediaRecorder can't recorder both side

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

**UPDATE 1:**

Some devices like SAMSUNG's, HTC's and more, have to use JNI to set AudioManager special parameters. For these devices you have to use `AudioRecord` object and use the MIC source.

**Question:**

I'm trying to record voice-call, The problem is that in the records I can hear only My side (MIC) instead of to hear both sides.

As i see it, its possible that i missed few configurations, or that i'm not using it correctly.

I have a static function that build a `MediaRecorder` object according to the configuration.

```
private static MediaRecorder getMediaRecorderByConf(RecordConfiguration conf) {
    MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(conf.getAudioSource());
    recorder.setOutputFormat(conf.getOutputFormat());
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(conf.getAudioEncoder());

    return recorder;
}
```

Configurations:

```
    CONF_1(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB, "amr", MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB),   
    CONF_2(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB, "amr", MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB),
    CONF_3(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4, "mp4", MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC),
    CONF_4(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4, "mp4", MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC),
    CONF_5(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT, "amr", MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT),
```

This is my constructor:

```
RecordConfiguration(int audioSource, int outputFormat, String fileSuffix, int audioEncoder) {
    this.audioEncoder = audioEncoder;
    this.outputFormat = outputFormat;
    this.fileSuffix = fileSuffix;
    this.audioSource = audioSource;
}
```